# Change background behind a UIViewAnimationTransition

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation, transition

When animating a transition to another view I am using the following code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"transition" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
        forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This works fine but during the flip animation there is a solid white background behind the animation. I was wondering if anyone knows a simple way to change the color of this background behind the animation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's should be the `backgroundColor` of your `UIWindow` or `keyWindow.rootViewController.view`.

Set the `backgroundColor` of every view below your animated view to `[UIColor blackColor]` should solve your problem (don't forget the UIWindow's backgroundColor too).

Answer (score 0):

I think the solid white background you see behind the animation is just the background color of whatever view is underneath. Simply changing the background color of that view (`view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]` or something like that) should change what you see underneath.